# Wrong handling when resuming from MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

My application is a quizz game. The user has a limited time to answer the question.

A timer is used for that. When the time runs out, a simple sound is triggered.

```
NSTimer *m_timer;
```

In function viewDidAppear:

```
m_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(decrementSpin) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

In my fisrt version, I encountered the following situation:

If during a question, an incoming call interrupts the game, the timer was still counting during the call.

I fixed this problem by adding in function viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidEnterInBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

- (void)appDidEnterInBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [[SoundManager sharedManager]stopMusic:NO];
    [m_timer invalidate];
    m_timer = nil;

}
- (void)appWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if(m_timer) {
        [m_timer invalidate];
        m_timer = nil;
    }
    //NSLog(@"%d", self.TimerbackgroundView.percent);
    m_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(decrementSpin) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

The function decrementSpin updates the clock image and plays the sound if the player has run out of time.

Everything works well.

Since my last version, I added a feature. The user can report a question (for incorrect content) by pressing a button.

When a button is pressed it opens the mail app with a prefilled content.

```
MFMailComposeViewController*mailComposerVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
     mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;
     [mailComposerVC setToRecipients:@emailAddress];
     [mailComposerVC setSubject:emailSubject];
     [mailComposerVC setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
     [self presentViewController:mailComposerVC animated:YES completion:^{

     }];

 }
 else{
     NSLog(@"Unable to send message");
 }

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```

It seems that my application doesn't handle correctly when the user sends the mail and returns to the Question page.

The timer doesn't pause (like the incoming call case), and in addition, when the Question page re-appears the clock-image shows the initial image (exactly like when the page appears for the first time)

This bug causes the sound (the one triggered when the user runs out of time) to be played during the next Page.

The only thing that comes in my mind that the events notified by UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification and UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification are not covered in the case of MFMailComposeViewController.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The app is still running the in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

So a possible solution would be to execute the same code of appDidEnterInBackground when opening the Mail.app, and to do the same as appWillEnterForeground in the body of

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```

What do you think ?